# Converting an image loading asynctask to rxjava, why is it lagging the ui?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to learn RxJava and I'm converting an `AsyncTask` I have to be an Observable/Subscriber. The original `AsyncTask` loaded an image in the background, then set an ImageView's drawable to that loaded image in `onPostExecute`. The images being shown are in a recyclerview, and as the list scrolls, an image is loaded for each item in the list. I converted it to Rx, but now there is a lot of lag when scrolling. The method `fetchThumbnail` is called everytime `onBind` is called in the RecyclerView's adapter. Below you will see my original implementation commented out, and the new implementation. I see no significant increase in memory or cpu usage when using RxJava. I believe I am subscribing and observing on the correct threads as well. What gives?

```
public class ThumbnailWorker {

    public static void fetchThumbnail(final Context context, final GalleryItem galleryItem, final int thumbId, final ThumnailFetchedListener completionListener) {

        galleryItem.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(null);
        galleryItem.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Observable.just(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
                thumbId
                , MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                null))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        completionListener.thumbnailFetched(galleryItem, bitmap, thumbId);
                        galleryItem.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });


//
//        new AsyncTask<Void,Bitmap,Bitmap>() {
//
//
//            @Override
//            protected void onPreExecute() {
//                super.onPreExecute();
//                galleryItem.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(null);
//                galleryItem.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
//                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
//                        thumbId
//                        ,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
//                        null
//                );
//
//                return bitmap;
//            }
//
//
//            @Override
//            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
//                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
//                completionListener.thumbnailFetched(galleryItem, bitmap,thumbId);
//                galleryItem.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//
//            }
//        }.execute();


    }
}
```

This is all that the listener is doing. The listener calls back to the adapter.

```
@Override
public void thumbnailFetched(GalleryItem item, Bitmap thumbnail, int thumbId) {
    if(thumbId == item.id) {
        item.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's one thing, you don't seem to unsubscribe anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of UI blocking is that the expression in the `just(...)` operator is executed in the current thread.

If you want to execute the expression in the thread you specified in the `subscribeOn(..)` then you have to create your `Observable` using `create(..)` method, not the `just(..)` one.

For you it would look like this:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>(){
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber){
            subscriber.onNext(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
                    thumbId
                    , MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                    null));

            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    completionListener.thumbnailFetched(galleryItem, bitmap, thumbId);
                    galleryItem.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Using `Observable.create` puts the burden on you regarding error handling and backpressure. `fromCallable` is a far more elegant solution.

Comment: I agree. The answer by @dwursteisen is more elegant. But you have to remember that `fromCallable()` does not share the result (emission) between subscribers, it'll execute passed function for each new subscriber.

Comment: Good point! I'm still kind of new to Rx, but wouldn't chaining a call to `cache()` remedy this behavior?

Comment: @npace , The `cache()` would give you such behaviour. But I just had to mention this part of the `fromCallable()` usage

Answer (score 6):

`Observable.just` can be used for already computed values.

I'm assuming that this call `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(...)` process your image and so may lag your UI. You have to defer your call. To do this, you can use `Observable.fromCallable` :

```
  Observable.fromCallable(() -> MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(), thumbId                 , MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(bitmap -> {
                    completionListener.thumbnailFetched(galleryItem, bitmap, thumbId);
                    galleryItem.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            });
```

Comment: What does it mean to defer the call? Does it mean background the call?

Comment: perform the call when you subscribe to the observable, not when you create the observable